# Is reverse-engineering crossword puzzles a thing?

Tags: crosswords, puzzle-identification

I was recently trying to recreate a crossword puzzle based off of a picture of half the puzzle and the answer key. I found it to be very enjoyable. Is this a thing? Is there anywhere that I can find reverse crossword puzzles that are designed to be "solved" this way?

Comment: i dont know if i should mention it or not but if you are satisfied by any answer then you should tick it as 'correct'.

Comment: @manshu Each answer only addresses half of the question. Unless one of them updates their answer to include the other's, I can't accept.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you may be interested in diagramless crosswords.

[image]

This is what they look like: you get clues, but no grid to work with.

[Here](http://crosswordfiend.blogspot.com/2007/12/what-do-you-do-with-diagramless.html)'s a guide on how to solve them, and [here](http://web.mit.edu/puzzle/www/2011/puzzles/zelda/forsaken_fortress/)'s one from the 2011 MIT Mystery Hunt (with an added twist once it's solved!)

Comment: My "puzzle" had the actual answers, not just the clues, but the concept is the same. However, I am more of looking for a puzzle solely involving the logistics of getting the words to fit, rather than solving the clues.

Comment: @ibid: I don't think that's common, but [this](http://web.mit.edu/puzzle/www/2014/puzzle/falling_into_place/) MIT puzzle involved that. (Before that step, you had to play a Tetris-style game.)

Comment: If any of these diagramless crosswords have answers to the clues written in a place which doesn't show the finished puzzle, than it would do the trick.

Comment: @ibid: None that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is most commonly given the extremely creative moniker of [fill-in puzzle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fill-In_(puzzle)). You are given an empty crossword grid and have to fill in the provided words.

Comment: Great, so I'm looking for diagramless fill-in puzzles.