# Where can I find diagramless fill-in puzzles?

Tags: crosswords, reference-request

From the answers that I got over [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/27502/is-reverse-engineering-crossword-puzzles-a-thing), I found out that the type of puzzle that I was looking for would be referred to as *diagramless fill-in puzzle*. (A cross of a diagramless crossword and a fill-in puzzle.)

#### Where can I find such puzzles?

Comment: Have you looked at this answer? 
[Answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/27503/17667)

Comment: @ABcDexter - Have you looked at my comment? [Comment](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/27502/is-reverse-engineering-crossword-puzzles-a-thing#comment82257_27502)

Comment: Aah, ok. I do understand your concern now. I hope I get time to help you :-)

Comment: Would this be solved by presenting you with puzzles that don't have clues at all, and just a bunch of words with an empty grid?

Comment: @IanMacDonald - Assuming it is solvable, than yes.

Comment: Isn't this question supposed to be asked on puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 1):

Some Penny Press puzzle variety books have one or two of the diagramless fill-in puzzles.  I also like them and have a hard time finding them.  For the Penny Press puzzles, they have a list of words and only the e's are in the diagram.  You have to determine the correct position from that.

Comment: I was hoping for some that are freely available online.

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, there are two books of Diagramless Fill-Ins (I have both of them myself) that exist.  You can purchase both of them on Amazon.

[https://www.amazon.com/Diagramless-Fill-Ins-I-Richard-Emmons/dp/0692319476/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1514566514&sr=8-1&keywords=diagramless+fill+in+puzzles](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0692319476)

[https://www.amazon.com/Diagramless-Fill-Ins-2-Richard-Emmons/dp/0986331228/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1514566514&sr=8-2&keywords=diagramless+fill+in+puzzles](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0986331228)

The last puzzle in each book is different (in the first book, it's a diagramless fill-in where you get all the O's instead of all the E's.  In the second book, the final puzzle is a diagramless crossword).

Comment: I was hoping for some that are freely available online. Still you've provided a link to a whole book of them. Maybe you could improve the answer by adding some information about the books(s) and a picture or two, rather than just links?